# Why wraping the useContext with useRef does not give any warning to add it as dependency while using it inside the useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

When I was using the **useContext** inside the **useEffect** it was giving me an warning saying it has to be added as a dependency.
But when I wrapped it inside a **useRef** it is not giving any warning.

**Before - when it was giving warning.**

```
const myContext = useContext(MyContext);
....
useEffect(() => {
    //Some Logic
    myContext.setSprinnerVisibility(true);
  }, []);
```

**After - when it was not giving any warning**

```
const myContextRef = useRef(useContext(MyContext));
....
useEffect(() => {
    //Some Logic
    myContextRef.current.setSprinnerVisibility(true);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Can you please help now..I have added my code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) initializes with whatever value is found in the parentheses. No dependency check needed since later changes won't update the `useRef`. On the other hand, [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) reacts to the dependency changes. Any variables that can change need to be recorded in the dependency array. `myContextRef` object reference doesn't change but the values within it may change.